# Sample size & T-Test for difference between classified groups?

Tags: classification, t-test, sample-size

Fundamentally I want to know:

*Do employees who promote a product, sell more of that product?*

The problem is that *employees who promote the product* is arbitrarily defined:

- I sample customers to determine if the employee promoted the product
- Each employee has **x** samples (**x** can be different for each employee)
- A sample can be positive (**p**) or negative (**n**)
- **x = p + n**
- I have defined *promoters* as employees in the top quartile of the ratio of **p/x** and *not promoters* as the bottom quartile

My approach is to compare the *sales* of the two groups of employees using a **two-tailed heteroscedastic T-test**.

My concern is the validity of of how the two groups of employees are defined in the first place.

- Is this method appropriate for classifying the two groups?
- How confident can I be that a *promoter* should be in that group - as in what is the probability that they got more positive (**p**) than negative (**n**) responses by chance?
- Should I exclude employees who have too few samples (and what is *too few*)?

  - E.g. should an employee with one positive response and two negative responses be included?
- Would it be different if customers rated how an employee promoted on a scale of 1 to 5 rather than a binary 0/1?